# Default control templates for windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to make some small modifications to the default control template of some controls in my windows phone 8 app. The problem is that I can't find these default templates. Anyone know where they can be found?

I am looking for something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but this is for WPF and not WP8.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a listing for WP8, however, you can use Blend or Visual Studio to edit a copy of a control's current template by right clicking on the control and then selecting **Edit Style**, **Edit Template** or **Edit Additional Templates** as appropriate. In the submenu, you can select **Edit a Copy...** which will present a window that allows you to create a copy of the default (or current template/stlye if you have already modified it) and customize it.

Answer (score 8):

You can find the file containing all the default control templates here:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Design\System.Windows.xaml**

Edit: also, the Windows Store Dev Center has a lot of them listed if you search for ["styles and templates"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/windows/apps?query=styles%20and%20templates&Refinement=180&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search&ac=4)