# Windows Phone 8.1 button color on tap

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a question regarding of changing button color in WP 8.1 on touch down or tap. I've already figured out how to change the background when there is no interaction, but I want to also change the background color of the button if it is tapped to transparent. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to modify the control template, as the "Pressed" state background is hard-coded into the control as "PhoneForegroundBrush":

```
          <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
            <Storyboard>
              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" />
              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
          </VisualState>
```

So copy-paste the entire default "ButtonBase" control template [from the SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18034439/1001985), and modify the above parts as needed.

On the one hand, if you want a consistent pressed color throughout your app, then it's easy -- just change the hard-coded color.   If on the other hand you want a different color for different buttons, then it's a bit trickier -- you'll have to subclass `Button`, and add a new "PressedBrush" dependency property to the control, then integrate that property into the control template.

Comment: this seems like it, but where can I find that template?

Comment: oh, never mind...I've found it recently...but will it work on all devices afterwards?

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy sure, why not?  As long as you don't do anything crazy.

Comment: and is it possible to change only for a specific buttons? hence I don't want to disable this feature in the future, just for 3 buttons

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy well, if you want the special style for only some buttons, then that's easy -- just give your new style an `x:Key`.  The default will remain the same.

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy it's only if you want different custom colors for different buttons that it gets trickier.