# Override default WP8.1 button colours

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to override the default Windows Phone 8.1 button colour which is displayed during a button press. Currently its getting a blue colour from somewhere, i have attempted to override the themes colours as shown below but its not having any effect. Is there a simple way to do this globally or even locally on a per button basis?

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#ed008c" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#ed008c" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneForegroundBrush" Color="#ed008c" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppAccentBrush" Color="#ed008c"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 button color on tap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064126/windows-phone-8-1-button-color-on-tap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not Silverlight, try this :

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonHover">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="3">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I have added it to my resource dictionary, though I'm nit familiar totally with what is going on inside? Which value should i change? Something inside the Pressed visual state perhaps?

Comment: put this code in App.xaml, then in your button write : Style = "{StaticResources ButtonHover}"