# wpf custom checkbox with text inside icon

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm new in xaml. I would like to create custom checkbox with text instead of default checkmark. Kind of

```
[Yes] Accept Value    (checked state)
[No] Accept Value     (unchecked state)
```

I don't want to use Images with "static" text. Can you please forward me to some sample or article, which will cover following scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will probably need to modify the default control template.  Here is a simple example of how you might do it:

```
<!--x:Key="PhoneCheckBox"-->
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="YesNoCheckBox">
  <Setter Property="Content" Value="Accept Value" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">

          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="[Yes]" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

          <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="CheckBackground" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" Height="32" Width="32"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="CheckText" Text="[No]" />
            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I just replaced the check symbol with a `TextBlock` that toggles between "[Yes]" and "[No]" (also removed the "Pressed", "Disabled", and "Indeterminate" visual state storyboards, for brevity).

[You can find the default control templates in your local SDK install.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18034439/1001985)

To use the above, just reference the style key:

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource YesNoCheckBox}" />
```

Comment: Good solution. Unfortunately there is not option to bind this value via some parameter, like <CheckBox ImageText="{Binding imageTextValue}" Content="The option" ... />

Comment: @MikhailDenisov that's easily solved too, though -- you just have to extend the `CheckBox` control and add dependency properties for "ImageText" or whatever else you need.

Comment: I was trying to implement new Windows Phone User Control with adding new parameter like "public partial class ValueCheckBox : CheckBox", got error: "Partial declarations of 'SampleProj.Controls.ValueCheckBox' must not specify different base classes". Also not sure about xaml's Grid content, as far as I understand I need to copy it from default CheckBox, can I take this from elements.xaml from SDK (copypasting - won't work)?

Comment: @MikhailDenisov I strongly suggest custom controls over user controls for this kind of thing.  It's a bit of a different approach to learn, but well worth the effort.  You should be able to find good info on this topic -- for example:  http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-wp7-custom-control-in-7-steps

Comment: So, is the only way of implementing is own user control? The only thing I need is custom text field which need's for binding. It is not clear for me how to pass parameters like IsChecked throught UserControl implementation.